# File Encryption in oracle application and sending it to Another server

Tags: oracle, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the file from Oracle ERP side and sending it to another external server.

I have used GPG console for file encryption, I am not getting how to automate the same process, as the ERP program which generates the file everyday is runs everyday and generates the file in the Unix server.

Please help me out.

Anusha

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried already?

Comment: first i generated the key id for erp server and signed the public key from outside server with erp key id. Then I encrypted the file using my passphrase. All these is done using GPG Console. I need to know how can I do it automatically or put the same GPG coomands in ERP code